# In a vf page which is rendered as pdf, i have a field in which value is 100,101.66 and i want that value to show as 100,102

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

In the code that I have given you below, I want the value in the basic total  to appear in the round-off figure means if it's supposed 100,101.66 then it should appear as 100,102. Right now in this code, it is showing 100,101. please let me know how it can be rectified. I have tried ceiling and math functions but it did not work

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="7">
        <p style="text-align: right;"> TOTAL  :</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,##0}" id="myNumberDisplay" rendered="{!llist[0].Basic_Selection__c == null}" >
            <apex:param value="{!ROUND((total * constant* currencyExchangeRate), 2)}"/><!--cnstant -->
        </apex:outputText>
        <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,##0}" id="myNumberDisplay3" rendered="{!llist[0].Basic_Selection__c != null}">
            <apex:param value="{!ROUND((basictotal),2)}"/>
           
        </apex:outputText>
    </td>
    
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,##0}">` is sufficient to round the value no need to apply additional ROUND function. In the below example if the Opportunity amount is 100,101.66 the VF page will show 100,102 and if the amount is 100,101.45 the VF page will show 100,101.

```
<apex:page standardController="opportunity" >
    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###}">
        <apex:param value="{!opportunity.amount}"/>
    </apex:outputText>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: i have made changes according to your comment but still not working. Could u please show me changes according to the code I have shared, I would really appreciate it.